# WebStorm local history flooded with prettier file watcher

Tags: webstorm, prettier

Using WebStorm 2019.3.2. I setup a file watcher for prettier, and have it configured with `Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher`. It works great, but when I try to use the Local History feature, it has hundred of entries, each time prettier runs.

I could only find in the doc a way to configure the retention of the Local History, not the frequency. Is it possible to reduce the number of entries when a prettier file watcher is enabled?

Comment: An entry is created on each file saving. And you have set up a watcher to save file on each change (not sure why you need your file to be re-formatted while you change it). Disabling *Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher* is the only way to go

Comment: I have a [performance problem](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43639) with WebStorm, and I found that if prettier runs often, for some reason the IDE is more responsive. So I will it keep it this way for now I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

File watchers or third-party plugins are no longer required for prettier in webstorm 2020.1
[changelog](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/2020-1/)

how to [configure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/prettier.html#ws_prettier_configure) prettier in webstorm

**EDIT**:

You can set prettier as default formatter in webstrom 2020.2
[changelog](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/2020-2/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.